# Proving $P\left( \bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \prod_{i = 1}^n P(A_i^c)$

Tags: probability-theory

The following exercise can be found in the excellent book Probability-1 by A.N. Shiryaev:

> Let $(\Omega,P)$ be a probability space and $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be independent events. Then $$P\left( \bigcup_{i =
>  1}^n A_i\right) = 1 - \prod_{i = 1}^n P(A_i^c)$$

I thougth of using the identity
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i =
 1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_i P(A_i) - \sum_{i < j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i < j < k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) + \dots (-1)^{n + 1}P(A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_n)$$ and then simply use the independence. My question:
Is there an easier way?

**Edit.** I have not proven yet that if $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are independent so are $A_1^c, \dots,A_n^c$ (so any suggestions on this proof would be appreciated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if $A_1,\dots,A_n$ are independent then so are $A_1^c,\dots,A_n^c$, hence
$$ \mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\Big)=1-\mathbb{P}\Big(\Big(\bigcup_{i=1}^nA_i\Big)^c\Big)=1-\mathbb{P}\Big(\bigcap_{i=1}^nA_i^c\Big)=1-\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(A_i^c)$$

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunately, I did not yet prove the thing with the complements. I wanted to use the identity in my question as a substitution of this fact. Would you mind to give me a reference on this fact (or maybe if the proof is very short you could add it)? I do know that if $A,B$ are independent so are $A^c,B^c$. So it should be induction.

Comment: There's a nice proof of this fact using the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, but in case you don't know that let me add to my answer a proof by induction.

Comment: @carmchael561 A proof by induction would be enough at the moment...I am just working on the details myself (I try to). But I will surely have a look at the other theorem! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, a proof by induction would probably amount to using the inclusion-exclusion principle as in your question. So I don't think that's any easier.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion principle together with independence isn't too bad, because the result is $1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-\mathbb{P}(A_i))=1-\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(A_i^c)$.

Comment: So it is basically what I had initially in my question, isn't it? Seems that I have to prove the other result by induction then.

Comment: Yes, if you don't already know that $A_1^c,\dots,A_n^c$ are independent then I'd say that the inclusion-exclusion principle is the way to go.